# "_pymodule.h" not found when compiling NUMBA

Tags: python, compilation, archlinux, numba

I am with Arch Linux.

Tried to install numba via both AUR and pip. This error comes in both cases:

```
numba/_dynfunc.c:1:23: fatal error: _pymodule.h: No such file or directory
 #include "_pymodule.h"
                   ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Any clue on how to solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Numba source code, and has now been fixed.

https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/392